# defaultValue Prop Not Working as Expected in Radix UI Accordion with Dynamic Children

Tags: reactjs, next.js, radix-ui, shadcnui

**Description:**
I'm using Radix UI's Accordion component in a Next.js project and encountering an issue where the `defaultValue` prop doesn't seem to work when the Accordion's children are dynamically generated. Despite setting `defaultValue`, the accordion items do not open by default as expected.

**Code Snippet:**
Here's how I've set up my accordion components:

*Page code:*

```js
<AccordionContextProvider>
  <div className="w-full">
    <TotalIngresosThisMonth />
  </div>
  <ClientSideAccordionManager>
    <AccordionContentWrapper itemId="item-1" title="Administrar ingresos">
      {/* Content for item-1 */}
    </AccordionContentWrapper>
    <AccordionContentWrapper itemId="item-2" title="Administrar fuente de ingresos">
      {/* Content for item-2 */}
    </AccordionContentWrapper>
    {/* Additional sections if needed */}
  </ClientSideAccordionManager>
</AccordionContextProvider>
```

*ClientSideAccordionManager:*

```js
export const ClientSideAccordionManager: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const { openItems, setOpenItems } = useAccordionContext();

  const handleValueChange = (value: string[]) => {
    setOpenItems(value);
  };

  return (
    <Accordion
      type="multiple"
      defaultValue={["item-1"]} // Attempted to set item-1 as the default open item
      value={openItems}
      onValueChange={handleValueChange}
    >
      {children}
    </Accordion>
  );
};
```

*AccordionContentWrapper:*

```js
"use client";
import { AccordionContent, AccordionItem, AccordionTrigger } from '@/components/ui/accordion';
import React from 'react';

export const AccordionContentWrapper: React.FC<{
  itemId: string;
  title: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ itemId, title, children }) => {
  return (
    <AccordionItem value={itemId}>
      <AccordionTrigger>{title}</AccordionTrigger>
      <AccordionContent>{children}</AccordionContent>
    </AccordionItem>
  );
};
```

**Expected Behavior:**
I expect the accordion item specified in the `defaultValue` prop to be open by default when the page loads.

**Actual Behavior:**
The accordion does not open any items by default, regardless of the `defaultValue` specified.

**Question:**
Could the issue be related to how the `children` prop is used or possibly a misunderstanding of how `defaultValue` should work with dynamically generated children? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.